# Is there a way to use the Nikon D300's timer for more than 999 exposures?

Tags: nikon, timelapse, nikon-d300

I recently experimented with using the timer in my D300 for a longer car ride ([the result can be seen here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNR--7jqUtY)). That went fairly well, but one thing that bugged me was that the timer stopped taking pictures after 999 exposures, so I had to fiddle a bit with the camera to restart it. Is there a simple way (that I obviously overlooked) to have the camera make more images, preferably until the card is full?

Answer (score 2):

How about using an intervalometer?

Comment: Yes, I guess would be the way to go. Would have been nice not needing to buy one when there is one built into the camera though...

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the only way to do it is to take more shots at the interval which, obviously, isn't what you're looking for. Anyways, according to Ken Rockwell, the formula is '# of intervals' x 'shots @ interval' = 'total shots' where the total shot value is calculated by camera. The # of intervals seems to be capped at 999.

Answer (score 1):

this remote:-

http://www.hahnel.ie/index.cfm?page=dslrremotecontrols&id=60&pId=60

from the faq

"When using the timer functionalities, is there a limit on the number of photographs I can take?
You can set the transmitter function N (number of shots) to "--". This then allows an indefinite amount of shots (above 99)."